# In Elder Sign how does removing a monster via a card effect work?

Tags: elder-sign

I am trying to figure out how to resolve "Flute of the Outer Gods" and "Bind Monster".
The Flute removes a monster after rolling. The Bind Monster does it at any time.

Can either item/spell be used mid-adventure?  When the monster is removed, does it reveal the task underneath that now must be completed? Is this different for the two cards?

When using the flute, does defeating the monster count as a success and allow a re-roll without assigning any dice nor losing a die (normal success)? Can you still complete a task on this die roll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coincidentally ti me asking, Elder Sign Omens just came out, and i was able to find out how some of these rules function in the digital version of the game.

As a disclaimer Omen rules are not identical in some ways to the paper board game. This particularly applies to when spell cards are used.

> Can either item/spell be used mid-adventure?

Yes they can be used at any roll

> When the monster is removed, does it reveal the task underneath that
>   now must be completed?

The task below a defeated monster does not have to be completed

> When using the flute, does defeating the monster count as a success
>   and allow a re-roll without assigning any dice nor losing a die
>   (normal success)?

No the monster is removed outside of die rolling.  You must still place dice on one of the tasks, or resolve a failure.